# Javascript Scoreboard for Snakegame

Tags: javascript

Im trying to create a Snake game with javascript.

Now I want to add a Scoreboard, that adds a point, if the snake lengt is + 1

At the beginning of the Game, the `tail = 5` (the lenght of the Snake in Blocks). So I made the `var score = tail -5`. The -5 is beacause when you start the game, the Snake has already a lenght of 5 blocks.

So for the Scoreboard I've created these vars

```
var score
var scoreBoard
```

And heres the rest of the code

```
    scoreBoard = new component ("30px", "Consolas", "red", 280, 40, "text");
    scoreBoard.text = "Score: " + score;
    scoreBoard.update();
```

The problem is.....i can't see the scoreboard, after I started the game.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We can't tell the problem without looking at a working example.

Comment: I used the example of the scoreboard function from this webpage. https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_score.asp